# Qt Exiting Event Loop

Tags: c++, qt

I want to monitor an Emergency Stop button in custom equipment attached to a Beaglebone, my code is developed with Qt 4.6.

At the moment, I successfully 'show' a message box (without any buttons) when the Emergency Stop button is pressed. What I want to do is to proceed with the program ***ONLY*** when the Emergency Stop button is released. The Button press/release emit separate signals on each event. However, using this code the EmergencyStopIsInactive signal is never detected.

```
QEventLoop loop;
connect(this, SIGNAL(EmergencyStopIsInactive()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec(QEventLoop::AllEvents);

qDebug() << "Emergency Stop Deactivated";
```

In fact, using breakpoints I can see that it is never generated. The Eventloop seems to not receive the signal.

If I comment out the loop.exec line, using breakpoints I can see that the code emits the signal. With the exec command back in, we never reach the breakpoints.

The exec() does not seem to be allowing the application to process events.

Can I get this to work the way I want? How?

Regards,
James

=======================================
Edit:
This is the code that generates the initial signal:

```
// Set up Emergency Stop Input
EmStop = new mita_gpio;
EmStop->initgpio_read(49);
connect(EmStop,SIGNAL(StateOutput(unsigned int)), this, SLOT(update_EmStop(unsigned     int) ) );
connect(EmStop,SIGNAL(StateOutput(unsigned int)), Test_Screen, SLOT(update_EmStop(unsigned int) ) );
connect(this,SIGNAL(EmergencyStopIsInactive()), Probe_Screen, SLOT(quit() ) );
connect(Probe_Screen,SIGNAL(ShowEmergencyStopScreen()),this,SLOT(EmergencyStopScreenShow()) );
```

This signal is then chained to the following:

```
void Manager::update_EmStop(unsigned int state_value)
{
    if (state_value == 1)
    {
        MitaData.EmergencyStop = 1;
        emit EmergencyStopIsActive();
        qDebug() << "Emergency Stop = 1";
    }
    else
    {
        MitaData.EmergencyStop = 0;
        emit EmergencyStopIsInactive();
        qDebug() << "Emergency Stop = 0";
    }
}
```

Comment: From where is it being emitted? Same thread? Could the event loop probably be blocking the emission?

Comment: Post the code that emits the signal as well.

Comment: You didn't change the `state_value` variable! It will always go into the same branch.

Comment: @Guilherme Bernal I wonder if you are correct? Because (as I said in the original post) if I comment out the loop.exec() line and put breakpoints in each branch, every time I push and release the button, it breaks in the correct branch. And only once in each branch. I think that my problem is that it never quits out of the event loop. Why would the event loop stop the emission?

Answer (score 2):

`SIGNAL(EmergencyStopIsInactive())` is executing in the main event loop of your program (I logically assume).

When you start a new event loop, you run it with the blocking function exec and thus despite your new loop is running, you are blocking the main event loop.

```
loop.exec(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
```

Since your signal is supposed to be sent from the main loop, that is blocked by your blocking function loop.exec, it will never be sent until the loop.exec is returning.

---

To solve that issue, whether generate the EmergencyStopIsInactive() signal from within the *"loop"* event loop, or put this second loop inside a separate thread.